# Execute function from another contract web3

Tags: solidity, web3js

```
Token Contract Owner = Crowdsale Owner (Another contract)
```

Token Contract have a function that only owner can execute. How can i execute using web3?

What i tried is below

```
var address = web3.eth.accounts[0]
  var data = Web3Utils.sha3('approveKyc([' + address + '])').slice(0, 10) + randomstring.generate({ length: 24, charset: '0'}) + address.substring(2)

  return meta.token.call(
    {
      to: '0xb84869e5eb3bfb5cb6df6f0c8af5b18fa2e3393f',
      data: data
    }
  )
```

Where `meta` is the Crowdsale contract instance.

Comment: You can execute it using web3 by calling it via web3.

Comment: BTW, the very small piece of code that you provided is neither Solidity nor Javascript, so it doesn't really contribute much here.

Comment: @goodvibration i will update the code what i tried

Comment: What is the expected and actual behavior? What web3 version do you use? You do not use the `from` field in the call. Does it even get executed?